# Cocoa Touch - Send Messages to Xbox 360 Friends

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

For my new app Im working on I want to be able to send messages on the app to xbox 360 friends . I Know its possible since they have them on the app store but how would I do it?

Thanks for any ideas/code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figure out what protocols are involved, learn to implement them or if they're existing (I honestly don't know) then use facilities already built in to communicate with a service which provides this.

You should do this, after this, you will have a better understanding of what needs to happen.

Comment: Yeah, there's no API, you have to mimic the actions the website takes, that's how I do it in Friendz :)